# Cannot upload file through dynamic file field in codeigniter with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to upload file using codeigniter, i have dynamic fields on my web page which i have created
and given it specific id. But when i upload the file through below code i get following error. 
This is because it does not recognizes file field of this id but after inspecting element the 
element of the specific id is present.Sometimes small file of around 1mb gets uploaded but 
uploading larger file gives the error.

> View:

```
function upload_video_Data(a)
{
 var formData = new FormData($("#posting_comment_"+a)[0]);

 $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/do_upload_comment/"+a,
        type: 'POST',
        async : false,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData:false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){

       },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
   });
}

<form name="posting_comment" id="posting_comment_<?=$row1['id']?>">
    <input type="file" name="save_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" class="movie_field" id="movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="file_m_id" value="<?=$row1['id']?>"/> 
    </span>   
    <input type="button" class="postbtn" id="submit_movie_<?=$row1['id']?>" value="Upload Video File" onclick = "return upload_video_Data(<?=$row1['id']?>)"/>  
</form>
```

> Controller:

```
    public function do_upload_comment($a)
    {    
      $comment_id=$this->input->post('file_m_id');
      $output_dir = "./uploads/";
      $type="video";

      $fileName = $_FILES["save_movie_".$comment_id]["name"];
      $extn = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["save_movie_".$comment_id]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName))
      {

         echo 'file upload';
      }
      else
      {
         echo 'file not uploaded';
      }

    }


Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: save_movie_76
Filename:controllers/dashboard.php 
Line Number: 231

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: save_movie_76
Filename:controllers/dashboard.php 
Line Number: 233
```

Comment: where is "enctype= multipart/form-data" in form? And where is ajax code?

Comment: @Amit- i have checked by including enctype but the same issue

Comment: getting data in var_dump($_FILES); There is also no form method so it is by default "GET" and you are accessing using post.

Comment: @Amit: output is <b> array </b> <i>(size=0)</i>
empty

Comment: if i check isset($_FILES["save_movie_".$comment_id]) the file array is empty

Comment: @Amit: I have checked for smaller files which could be around 1mb it is working fine but above 1 mb it gives error message.

Comment: Have you checked you `php.ini`  max_upload and max_post settings? What are they? Any errors?

Comment: @Kisaragi - Yes i have increased the limit of upload but the same issue is coming.

Comment: Both max upload AND max post?